# GNU/Linux RPC Multithread Support

Tags: linux, multithreading, rpc

We are migrating ONC/RPC applications from Solaris to GNU/Linux. The applications are written in C and C++.

The applications call rpc_control() with RPC_SVC_MTMODE_SET to set "multithread mode", RPC_SVC_CONNMAXREC_SET to set "non-blocking max rec size", RPC_SVC_USE_POLLFD to set "number of file descriptors to unlimited", etc.

Apparently rpc_control() can't resolved on GNU/Linux.

Does anyone know if multithread RPC is supported on GNU/Linux? If it does, what the substitute call is?

Thank you!